# VB2010: How Would I run this extraction process in a backgroundworker with progressbar

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

So I made a small extraction program which just extracts a zip file to a location, and it also shows the progress of the extraction. But the problem is that whenever it's extracting large zips, the program kinda freezes while extracting and if you go off the process, you can't go back onto it until it's finished extracting, but you can still see the progressbar's progress. This is the code I have so far:

Form2.vb

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then

        Else
            ProgressBar1.Visible = True
            Button2.Enabled = False
            Button3.Enabled = False
            TextBox1.Enabled = False
            Unzip("FileToExtract.zip", "PathToExtractTo")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Unzip.vb

```
Imports Ionic.Zip

Module SimpleUnzip
    Public Sub Unzip(ByVal ZipToUnpack As String, ByVal DirectoryToExstractTo As String)
        Try
            Using zip As ZipFile = ZipFile.Read(ZipToUnpack)
                Form2.ProgressBar1.Maximum = zip.Entries.Count
                Dim entry As ZipEntry
                For Each entry In zip
                    entry.Extract(DirectoryToExstractTo, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently)
                    Form2.ProgressBar1.Value = Form2.ProgressBar1.Value + 1
                Next
            End Using
        Catch ex1 As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

So I have tried things like putting the SimpleUnzip sub in a background worker on the main forum and calling that, but that doesn't work at all, I have also tried a background worker on the module, it extracts but the progressbar doesn't work. Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As with any task using a `BackgroundWorker`, you do the work in the `DoWork` event handler and then you call `ReportProgress` to report the progress.  This line:

```
Form2.ProgressBar1.Maximum = zip.Entries.Count
```

and this line:

```
Form2.ProgressBar1.Value = Form2.ProgressBar1.Value + 1
```

are going to have to be replaced with calls to `ReportProgress`.  In the `ProgressChanged` event handler, you do what you normally would, i.e. update the `ProgressBar`.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example, I get what you mean but don't know how I would be able to do it.

Comment: There are examples of using a `BackgroundWorker` all over the place.

Comment: I mean for my project, I know how to use the background worker, just don't know how i'd put my project in it

Comment: So you didn't actually mean an example then, but rather to write your code for you.  You know how to use a `BackgroundWorker` and you get what I mean but, in the minute or so that you've had to contemplate my instructions, you just can't work out how to follow them.  Maybe you should spend more than just a minute or so thinking about it.